# How to change template file name and destination for some blocks?

Tags: 7, theming, blocks

For example: I want to change default login block template.

My current template file is — /sites/all/themes/{theme_name}/templates/block--user--login.tpl.php

But I want — /sites/all/themes/{theme_name}/templates/**system_blocks/login-block.tpl.php**

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [template_preprocess_block](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.module/function/template_preprocess_block/7). You can do this with the following code in your theme's `template.php` file:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  // Perform a check based on any parameter, e.g. block ID.
  if ($variables['block_html_id'] == 'block-system-main') {
    // This will lookup for block--system-main-block.tpl.php file in your
    // theme.
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'] = 'block__system_main_block';
  }
}
```

However, Drupal already looks for various template names, before it settles down for the default `block.tpl.php`. Here is the list:

1. block--block--[block-id].tpl.php
2. block--[module]--[delta].tpl.php
3. block--[module].tpl.php
4. block--[region].tpl.php
5. block.tpl.php

See [this](https://drupal.org/node/104319) page for more information.